# in matlab, how to read space separated two column integer data from file?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

For example, I have a file dog_test.txt like this (length almost 10,000).

```
000001  1
000002 -1
000003 -1
000004 -1
000006 -1
000008 -1
000010 -1
000011 -1
000013 -1
000014 -1
000015 -1
000018  1
000022 -1
000025 -1
...
```

I wanted to see the distribution of the index together with the 1,-1 values. (two values as (x,y) point.).  So I did

```
M = dlmread('dog_test.txt');
M1=M; M1(:,2)=[];
M2=M;M2(:,1)=[];
plot(M1,M2);
```

and can see
[image]

I'm not well versed in matlab, so I think it should be possible to draw the plot directly from M. How can I do that?

Comment: `plot(M(:,2),M(:,1))` ?

Comment: Plot looks fine to me.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: have a look at his code, he wants `plot(M(:,1), M(:,2))`

Comment: @Andy ah yes, my mistake.

Comment: Ah, plot(M(:,1),M(:,2)) does it. (I tried similar thing but with error.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've got a number of tests and a classification result (-1 or +1), correct? In which case, a better plot is probably a stem plot. e.g

```
X = 1 : 50; Y = [-1,1]; Y = Y(randi([1,2], 1, 50)); % create random dataset

stem (X, Y,                       ...  % "..." allows you to continue below
      'linestyle', '--',          ...  % dotted lines
      'linewidth', 3,             ...  % width of '2'
      'color', 'k',               ...  % black color lines
      'markeredgecolor', 'r',     ...  % red outline for markers
      'markerfacecolor', 'green', ...  % green 'filling' for markers
      'markersize',15);                % bigger markers

axis([0,50,-1.5,1.5]);                 % adjust axis limits
```

[image]

(so, in your case:)

```
stem (M(:, 1), M(:, 2));
```